# Connecting a wcf service from a server wsdl file

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-core, connected-services

I am working on .net 6 project and I need to have net461 package. In a test server that is hosted as a different service. I can connect that one as a connected service to my project. My concerns are,

1. Adding that service from a particular server is it always connected to that server or is it working as a separate service in my project?
2. Is it a best practice to have a connected service performance-wise?
3. Adding reference is a one-time process or is it always connected with the WSDL url link?

I added a service from a server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all, the first question. Typically, the client calls the server's services over the HTTP protocol. The HTTP protocol has persistent and non-persistent connections. Persistent connectivity is currently the dominant mode of operation. Unless a server is a special server, it is impossible to serve a client alone. This would be costly.

2.There are many factors that affect service performance: such as server performance, network speed, service code and client performance.

3.If it is an HTTP persistent connection, then adding a reference is persistent, and if the server is down, the service is finished. Non-persistent HTTP connections are also discussed on a case-by-case basis.
At the same time, services can also be completed through other protocols, such as TCP.

This is what I have summed up in my work, and if there are errors, I am very grateful to bring them up.